# How to use str_replace when using html5 form placeholders when a value is empty or not required?

Tags: php, html

How to use str_replace as a placeholder when a value is empty,null or not required. This is after I have added my record and am sending an Templated Email. This example works except for the issue with the placeholders. How can I change this to show blank using str_replace. This is just a sample there are many fields in complete project.

This is PHP 7.0 and Html5 on Windows IIS.

```
function AfterAdd($values, $keys, $inline, $pageObject)
{
$email_message =  file_get_contents("New_Customer_Form.htm");
    $email_message = str_replace("##City##",$values["City"],$email_message);
    $email_message = str_replace("##phone##",$values["phone"],$email_message);

    $email=$values["fldadminemail"];
    $subject="New Record Added"; 

    $arr = runner_mail(array('to' => $email, 'subject' => $subject, 'htmlbody' => $email_message, 'charset' => 'UTF-8'));
}
```

I want to show whitespace( blank ) when field value is empty,null or not required. What I get now if the above occurs is the placeholder ##City##.

Comment: You could try using a condition on e.g. the value of `$values["City"]`?

Comment: I thought of that but wouldn't I have to add a condition on every field? This is just a sample and there are numerous fields and other pages in my project, so I was trying to avoid adding a condition for each one. Thanks

Comment: You say that you still get `##City##` after your `str_replace('##City##', ...)`? I don't see how that's possible. Even if the key `$values['City']` doesn't exist, it should be replaced with an empty value (and throw a notice about undefined index). [Here's a demo](https://3v4l.org/gqRec)

Comment: If City value is empty or null. The placeholder is generated instead of a value. Are you saying the placeholder should automatically generate a blank or whitespace using str_replace? Thanks

Comment: Did you check the link I posted?

Comment: Yes , your syntax is a bit different though. The code I have works with no errors thrown. Just replaces the placeholder with the placeholder if value is empty,null .

Comment: In what way was the syntax different? It's just a `str_replace()`? Anyway, it should only replace it with the placeholder if `$values['City']` contains the string `##City#`. You would also only get those warnings if the key doesn't exist in the array at all. My point was that I don't see how it would _leave_ the placeholder instead of replacing it, regardless if the key exists or not.

Comment: You are correct . I had an older html form and changed this particular form to html5 form or newer form. Which should have nothing to do with it but , all of a sudden I get the whitespace instead of the placeholder . Problem solved. Thanks Magnus!